# using limit and where clause to make pagination

Tags: mysql

Everybody . please help me. Now I'm working with pagination.. I want to display 5 records per page depending on the tblcategory.cat_id . but my query string has problem..

1. table tblcategory

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcategory` (
     `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `cat_name` char(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
2. table tblcontent

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcontent` (
     `con_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `title` char(100) NOT NULL,
     `description` text NOT NULL,
     `date_posted` date NOT NULL,
     `author` char(50) NOT NULL,
     `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`con_id`),
     KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=78 ;
3. table tblimage

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblimage` (
     `img_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `con_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `img_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     `img_thum` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`img_id`),
     KEY `con_id` (`con_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

this is my query string , so what's wrong with my sql statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tblcontent LEFT JOIN tblcategory
    ON (tblcontent.cat_id = tblcategory.cat_id)
    LEFT JOIN tblimage ON (tblimage.con_id = tblcontent.con_id)
    ORDER BY tblcontent.date_posted DESC
    LIMIT 0,5 WHERE tblcategory.cat_id=1
```

The Result is :
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE tblcategory.cat_id=1' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM tblcontent LEFT JOIN tblcategory
    ON (tblcontent.cat_id = tblcategory.cat_id)
    LEFT JOIN tblimage ON (tblimage.con_id = tblcontent.con_id)
  WHERE tblcategory.cat_id=1
    ORDER BY tblcontent.date_posted DESC
    LIMIT 0,5
```

First you need to specify the where condition and then specify the order

see here for [Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` is misplaced - it needs to be before the `ORDER BY`.

I.e.

```
SELECT * FROM tblcontent
LEFT JOIN tblcategory ON (tblcontent.cat_id = tblcategory.cat_id)
LEFT JOIN tblimage ON (tblimage.con_id = tblcontent.con_id)
WHERE tblcategory.cat_id=1
ORDER BY tblcontent.date_posted DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```